# I want to add a new value to the Post Form Before I Redirect it using the ReverseProxy

Tags: go, reverse-proxy

I'm writing a ReverseProxy with special requirement using GOLANG
The ReverseProxy  works just fine.
But I have a problem with the special requirement
the users send Http Post Form
contains user and email
I want to add a new value to the Post Form
For example url
Before I Redirect it using the ReverseProxy

this is my proxy code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    origin, _ := url.Parse("http://localhost:9000/")

    director := func(req *http.Request) {
        req.Header.Add("X-Forwarded-Host", req.Host)
        req.Header.Add("X-Origin-Host", origin.Host)
        req.URL.Scheme = "http"
        req.URL.Host = origin.Host
    }

    proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

I tried `R.Form.add`
and `r.PostForm.add`
and `r.Form.set`  `r.PostForm.set`
It's not working.

Comment: What's the problem? Is there any attempt?

Comment: You already have the director function. Just replace the request body with the amended form. You may also have to update the [ContentLength field](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ContentLength).

Comment: @Зелёный
I couldn't find a way to do that.
I STFW AND RTFM But I couldn't figure it out

Comment: @Peter
Can you tell me how to do that?
Do you have a simple example

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```golang
func main() {
    origin, _ := url.Parse("http://localhost:9000/")

    director := func(req *http.Request) {
        req.Header.Add("X-Forwarded-Host", req.Host)
        req.Header.Add("X-Origin-Host", origin.Host)
        req.URL.Scheme = "http"
        req.URL.Host = origin.Host
    }

    proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        r.ParseForm()
        form := r.Form
        form.Add("hello", "world")
        body := form.Encode()
        r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(strings.NewReader(body))
        r.ContentLength = int64(len(body))
        proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```